# Tkinter - rotate image with slider simultaneously

Tags: python, tkinter, rotation

UPDATED -

New to tkinter

Is it possible to rotate a picture by using a slider simultaneously.

I have an image of a rotatory dial, beneath this image is a slider listed from 0 to 360. I would like the image to rotate clockwise as the slider is moved from 0 to 360, and anticlockwise as the slider is returned from 360 to 0.

ROTATION OF IMAGE WITH SLIDER WORKS CORRECTLY

I have ran into a bug, the image is black. Perhaps the image is too zoomed in? Apologies, I am new to python and tkinter.

Here is how the GUI should look [Correct GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIgHF.png)

THIS IS HOW THE GUI LOOKS NOW [Incorrect GUI with Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsEJ0.png)

THIS IS HOW THE GUI LOOKS REMOVING THUMBNAIL LINE [THUMBNAIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7PYP.png)

Here is the updated code

```
# import necessary modules
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

 
root = Tk()
root.title("Gesture Detection Application")
root.geometry("400x320") # set starting size of window
root.maxsize(400, 320) # width x height
root.config(bg="#6FAFE7") # set background color of root window
 
Heading = Label(root, text="Demonstrator Application2", bg="#2176C1", fg='white', relief=RAISED)
Heading.pack(ipady=5, fill='x')
Heading.config(font=("Font", 20)) # change font and size of label
   

image = Image.open("rotate_dial.png")
width, height = image.size
image.thumbnail((width/5, height/5))
photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image_label = Label(root, image=photoimage, bg="white", relief=SUNKEN)
image_label.image = photoimage
image_label.pack(pady=5)

def rotate_image(degrees):
    new_image = image.rotate(-int(degrees))
    photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_image)
    image_label.image = photoimage #Prevent garbage collection
    image_label.config(image = photoimage)
    

w2 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=360, tickinterval= 30, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, command = rotate_image)
w2.pack()
w2.set(0)
                                                                                            
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter doesn't have a way to rotate images. Do you know  how to rotate it and are asking how to sync it with a slider, or are you asking how to rotate an image?

Comment: Both - I'm not sure how to rotate the image, and how to sync it with the slider?

Comment: There are questions on this site related to rotating images. Perhaps you should try some of those answers before asking a similar question.

Comment: I have unfortunately - I am finding it difficult, especially syncing the slider with the rotation

Comment: First you said you're asking how to rotate an image, and then you said you've tried rotating it. If you know how to rotate an image, show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate the image using PIL (which you've already imported). You can link it to the Scale by adding a command.

```
image = Image.open("rotate_dial.png")
width, height = image.size
image.thumbnail((width/5, height/5))
photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image_label = Label(root, image=photoimage, bg="white", relief=SUNKEN)
image_label.pack(pady=5)

def rotate_image(degrees):
    new_image = image.rotate(-int(degrees))
    photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_image)
    image_label.image = photoimage #Prevent garbage collection
    image_label.config(image = photoimage)
    

w2 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=360, tickinterval= 30, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, command = rotate_image)
```

Instead of creating a `PhotoImage` initially, it now creates a PIL `Image` object. It then uses the height and width and the `thumbnail` function to replace the `subsample`. Then it uses `ImageTk` to turn it into a tkinter `PhotoImage` which is shown in the label. The Scale now has a command, `rotate_image`, which recieves the scale value, which is the number of degrees, and then uses PIL to create a new rotated image, which is then turned into a `PhotoImage` and displayed in the label by changing it's image with `.config`. Now when you move the slider, the image rotates with it.

Comment: OP wants rotation in clockwise, so negative value should be passed to `image.rotate()`.  Also better set the `fillcolor` option of `image.rotate()` to the same background color of the image as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I can see clearly how to go about this task now. Unfortunately I have ran into a bug. Using your code above, the image is black and the slider does not appear on the window. I shall add my code above by updating my question to clearly demonstrate - I would really appreciate it if you could have a look. Thank you

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks, I missed that. I'm not sure what you mean with `fillcolor` though.

Comment: @GeorgeQuine The slider does not appear because you are missing `w2.pack()` and `w2.set(0)` at the end. It looks like the image is getting garbage collected, so add `image_label.image = photoimage` after the `image_label = Label` line and above `image_label.pack(pady=5)` . Also, please make sure to change `image.rotate` to use `-int(degrees)` so it rotates clockwise.

Comment: @Henry When the image is rotated, the area near the four corners may need to be filled with pixels to make the rotated image having the same width and height.  The color of those pixels is black by default.  So if the background color of the image is white, there may be black corners in the rotated image. You can refer the official document on [Image.rotate](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate).

Comment: @Henry Great the slider has appeared, although the image is still black. There is a small white pixel visible within the image which shows that the slider and the rotation of the image works correctly in both directions. Once the image is set correctly, this task should be finished - thank you

Comment: Can you link a screenshot of what you see, I can't seem to reproduce it.

Comment: Screenshot can be found in question here "THIS IS HOW THE GUI LOOKS NOW Incorrect GUI with Slider"

Comment: Thanks, does removing the `image.thumbnail` line do anything?

Comment: Unfortunately not - That just makes the thumbnail the same size as the window. Screenshot found in question. Is the image too big or too small?

Comment: I don't think that's it, if it's not getting garbage collected I'm not sure what's wrong, sorry.

Comment: @GeorgeQuine Does adding `expand = True` to `image.rotate(...)` do anything useful?